# ArcGIS crashes on opening GDB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase

I do not have a great experience in ArcGIS, but recently I received 3 datasets in ArcGIS Geodatabase format, which I would like to work on. From these 3 datasets I can open only 1, but not the other 2, because after the successful layer selection ArcGIS simply crashes without any error message.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3. I also tried to open them with the most recent version of the free ArcGIS Explorer on another computer, with exactly the same result. I contacted the office from whom I received the data and we verified in their office that they can open the data on their computers from the very same external hard disk I was using before, therefore the data is valid. They were using ArcGIS 10.1 and 10.3 on their computers.

I am totally out of idea what is causing this issue, and it is also not helping that there are no error messages at all. If you have any advise please share.

**UPDATE:**
For request, the progress of facing the issue through screenshots is shown below:

*Step 1:* adding data
[image: adding data]

*Step 2:* selecting layer
[image: selecting layer]

*Step 3:* crashing
[image: crashing]

**Update #2:** crash info by Windows

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: E3.exe
  Application Version:  2.0.0.3400
  Application Timestamp:    55b913ce
  Fault Module Name:    FileGDB.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.0.0.3400
  Fault Module Timestamp:   55b948ff
  Exception Offset: 000c82f9
  Exception Code:   c0000409
  Exception Data:   00000000
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1038
  Additional Information 1: 9f85
  Additional Information 2: 9f8512db2514abc8411174b85319aee2
  Additional Information 3: 9270
  Additional Information 4: 92708c4c8f00576bcf7d8ffce69d82f8
```

Comment: Can you add any screenshots of the data and what you are doing?

Comment: File corruption affects the **copy** not the original.  Just because the original was good does not mean your copy is valid.

Comment: @Vince They tested **my copy**, because I brought there my external disk and they were opening the data from that disk. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: @DMusketeer: ofc, I updated my question.

Comment: looks like a re-install of arcgis is required. was the geodatabase created in a new version of arcgis?

Comment: If it's not the data, then it's your system.  You can try resetting your application profile first:  https://geonet.esri.com/thread/78692

Comment: Could it be the size of the data, and your system resources?

Comment: @Mapperz I already tried it on 3 computers, on 2 of them with totally clean installs of ArcGIS. The result is always the same, 1 dataset works totally fine, the other 2 crashes the application. I don't know the version of the geodatabases, can I retrieve it somehow?

Comment: I improved the question with the event crash log I managed to get out of Windows. It shows that the FileGDB.dll is crashing, but that is no surprise since that is the driver for the format.

Comment: @RichardLaw Well, the database is around 2GB and my computer has 8GB of memory, so I don't think so. Also, it crashes immediately after it starts reading the data.

Comment: @Mapperz: based on only the folder name, one of the geodatabases which I have issue with was created with ArcGIS 9.3. I guess it should be compatible with my ArcGIS 10.3, isn't it?

Comment: ArcCatalog also reports version 9.3 for all the geodatabases. It can read that info, but if I want to interact with a layer, it also crashes.

Comment: The BEX error relates to anti virus protection - switch it off